# Operations on python datatypes

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im new to python and tensorflow. How can I check what operations can be done on a variable ? Im trying to store images into a list. Id like to find out its size just to confirm.

This is the code taken from the website.

```
# Typical setup to include TensorFlow.
import tensorflow as tf

# Make a queue of file names including all the JPEG images files in the relative
# image directory.
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("./images/*.jpg"))

# Read an entire image file which is required since they're JPEGs, if the images
# are too large they could be split in advance to smaller files or use the Fixed
# reader to split up the file.
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

print(len(filename_queue))
```

I got an error below. This is the website for the function string_input_producer https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline#string_input_producer it does say it returns a list so im not sure what im doing wrong

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_load_jpg.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(len(filename_queue))
TypeError: object of type 'FIFOQueue' has no len()
```

Comment: Try print dir(variable) - it prints a list of methods and operations.

Comment: *"it does say it returns a list"* - the docs you link to actually say *"**Returns:**  A queue with the output strings."* If you want to know what methods a FIFOQueue has, Google it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use `dir(filename_queue)` to check the set of functions in an object. This outputs the following -

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 
 '_check_enqueue_dtypes', '_dequeue_return_value', '_dtypes',
 '_name', '_names', '_queue_ref', '_scope_vals', '_shapes',
 'close', 'dequeue', 'dequeue_many', 'dequeue_up_to', 'dtypes',
 'enqueue', 'enqueue_many', 'from_list', 'name', 'names',
 'queue_ref', 'shapes', 'size']
```

Make use of the `size()` function to get your result. You can read more about [`FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/queues#FIFOQueue).

Comment: great thanks ! that worked ! May I know however, why dir(tf.train.string_input_producer) gives me something different although filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(...) ?

Comment: you're welcome! This is because `tf.train.string_input_producer` is a function and not an object